# add my own class in admin field django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms

Hi everyone Y create my own app in djando CMS, now I want to add my own class and id's to my field.. y try this, but I don't obtain any successful result.

in my model.py I have this

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  TYPES_CHOICES = ( 
    ('none', 'not specified'),
    ('s', 'Series'),
    ('mb', 'Multiples Bar'),
    ('b', 'Bar suggestion'),
  )
  app_config = AppHookConfigField(HealthConfig)
  code = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=250)
  url_suggestion = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=250, verbose_name="URL for Suggestion" )


  health_placeholder = PlaceholderField('health_info')
  objects = AppHookConfigManager()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.url

  class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
```

and now in my form.py I have this

```
from django import forms
from .models import Entry


class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Entry
    fields = '__all__'


  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['code'].widget.attrs={ 
      'id': 'my_code', 
      'class': 'code_class', 
    }
```

finally my admin.py is like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import PlaceholderAdminMixin
from .cms_appconfig import HealthConfig
from .models import Entry
from .forms import EntryForm
from aldryn_apphooks_config.admin import ModelAppHookConfig, BaseAppHookConfig


class EntryAdmin(ModelAppHookConfig, PlaceholderAdminMixin,  admin.ModelAdmin):
  # pass

  fieldsets = (
    ('General data', {
      'fields':('app_config','chart', 'url',('count', 'code', 'start'))
    }),
    ('Suggestion',{
      'classes':('collapse', 'suggestion',),
      'fields':('url_suggestion',('key1_suggestion_name','key1_suggestion'),('key2_suggestion_name','key2_suggestion'), 'primary_suggestions')
    }),
  )

  list_display =('app_config' ,'url', 'chart');

  list_filter = (
    'app_config',
  )

  form = EntryForm

  class Media:
    js = ('health/js/admin/healthAdmin.js',)
    css = {
      'all': ('health/css/admin/admin_area.css',)
    }

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

any idea is I missing something, after that, I do a migrate of the component again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Hi @markwalker_ I try to add the same class to my fields, inside the admin, because depends on the option that I select I hidden or show some fields. In that case I try to add the `class="code"`  to my field code. but don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom form for admin using the `form` attribute of `ModelAdmin`.

So using the example from the docs linked below, that would look like;

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Person


class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ['name']


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['age']
    form = PersonForm
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

So in your `admin.py` you'd need something like;

```
from .forms import EntryForm

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EntryForm
```

Comment: Thanks @markwalker_ your solution help me to add new class to my field. I modifed my answer with your solution